# WP-RestAPI and xml sitemap

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, rest-api, google-xml-sitemaps

Using the WP-RestAPI to pull a wordpress blog into an angularjs application.  Works extremely well.  The blog is using Yoast SEO for the for meta descriptions and keywords.  I would like to use the yoast xml sitemap as well for submitting to google. However, because of route structure I need to save the sitemap to a different location than the root wordpress folder.  I have also tried using the Google Sitemap Generator plugin.  With neither plugin can I seem to change where the sitemap is saved. Looking for any advice on how I could make this work.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to put your REST API endpoints into a sitemap, they're not intended for human consumption ( REST endpoints return data, not HTML ), and sitemaps are for human readable pages, aka pages that show up in google. If I've misunderstood can you please edit your question to clarify what you meant, including examples

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do.  The actual website url is www.mywebsite.com.  It contains the application and pulls in and displays the blog via the rest api.  The wordpress url is wordpress.mywebsite.com.  That is not accessable to the out side world. However I would like to use the site map either plugin creates for all my pages.  however neither plugin can write to the www.mywebsite.com directory

Comment: So your pages don't exist in WordPress, they're entirely within the realm of javascript, and populate themselves via REST?

Comment: @jppower175 Could you tell others how you got the meta desc and keywords from the Yoast SEO to a REST API endpoint? Thanks.

Comment: @Kano the same way you get any meta data added to the api end point.  [API Docs - Modifying API responses](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/)

Comment: @jppower175 thanks.. What I meant was how did you handle generating the tags that Yoast does on page visits? There's only a few fields a user can add under page or Yoast's settings and others are generated dynamically. I'd like to retrieve all of those tags/their content through the REST API.

Comment: @Kano The only data from Yoast I am using is the meta description, keywords, and SEO title.  All of which are stored as meta data.  All other SEO elements are handled via custom fields or in the front end for my application.  I suggested starting your own question that has some examples of what you are trying to do as I am not entirely sure.

Comment: @jppower175 Sorry for cluttering the comments feed. Already figured it out. But thanks for shedding some light and bearing with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your plugin is writing to the `/usr/share/wordpress/sitemap_index.xml` filesystem location, but you want it can be accessed through `http://www.website.com/sitemap_index.xml` as if the xml file were stored in `/var/www/html/sitemap_index.xml`. You can use the alias directive then, available in mainstream webservers Apache and NginX:

For an [alias in NginX](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias), you put this inside the `server` of your public website:

```
location /sitemap_index.xml {
    alias /usr/share/wordpress/sitemap_index.xml;
}
```

For [Apache the alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) it's like this, inside the virtual host of your website:

```
Alias "/sitemap_index.xml" "/usr/share/wordpress/sitemap_index.xml"
```

Again, I'm only assuming filepaths and filenames, but if you need more specific directives, for another webserver, or differente paths/names, please comment it, or even better: update your question to make my answer match.